# jQuery Select2 Trigger Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using `Select2` as my plugin for drop-downs & AJAX based lookups.

On my initial submission form, I have a `select2` drop down called "Type". I have an `on` event listening for that dropdown to change and then triggering another function when that happens.

```
$('[name=in_type]').on("select2-selecting", function(e) {

  console.log(e)

    // Define our vars
    var requestTypeID = e.val,
        requestTypeText = e.object.text;

    // Based on the type
    generateForm(requestTypeText);

});
```

When I log the event to the console, I see an object called `object` in which I am able to access the text from and use it in my function.
[image]

**-- Fast forward to my "Edit Form" page--**

When a user comes back to edit a record, I have to set the value of the `type` field and then trigger the `select2-selecting` programmatically.

I do that like so:

```
$('[name=in_type]').select2('data', {id:requestObj.requestType, text:requestObj.requestTypeName});
  var evt = $.Event("select2-selecting", {
    val: requestObj.requestType, // I have also tried passing ID instead of val
    text: requestObj.requestTypeName
  });
$("[name=in_type]").trigger(evt);
```

When this function gets triggered by the event above, there is no `object` that is logged to the console like there is when I manually change the fields.

I assume there the event I am trying to pass isn't including the object correctly or something of that nature?

On the edit page, I can literally click on the drop down myself, change it and it logs the object just fine. This does not happen when I trigger it programmatically which makes me thing I am missing something that should be passed or doing it incorrectly.

[image]

**Summary of my question:**

How can I programmatically pass the object to the select2 event to keep the same format as when changing it manually?